# Bounds of double factorial

Tags: factorial, upper-lower-bounds

I am looking for bounds on the double factorial for even and odd $n \in \mathbb{N}$, defined as

$$
 n!! = n \cdot (n-2) \cdot (n-4) \dots
$$

For example, $9!! = 9 \cdot 7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1$ and $8!! = 8 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2$, see [Double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). It is clear for me that

$$
 n! = (n!!)((n-1)!!)
$$

holds, such that if I have some bounds for the factorial

$$
b^-_n \leq n! \leq b^+_n
$$

I can obtain bounds for the double factorial

$$
\frac{b^-_n}{(n-1)!!} \leq n!! \leq \frac{b^+_n}{(n-1)!!}
$$

which can be used recursively, e.g.

$$
\frac{b^-_1 b^-_3 b^-_5}{b^+_2 b^+_4}
\leq
3!!
\frac{b^-_5}{b^+_4}
\leq
\frac{b^-_5}{4!!}
\leq 
5!!
\leq
\frac{b^+_5 b^+_3 b^+_1}{b^-_4 b^-_2}
\ .
$$

I have used bounds $b^\pm_n$ based on Stirling's approximation, see [Speed of convergence and error estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates), but due to the recursive use, the estimate is too far away for large $n$.

**Question: do you know better (explicit) bounds for the double factorial?**

**Edit (2018-06-28):** 
In order to provide a clearer view concerning Alex's comment, gammatester comment and and Gerry's answer (see his answer), consider the factorial bounds, see [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)
$$
b^\pm_n = c^\pm_n \beta_n 
\ , \quad
\beta_n = n^{n+1/2} e^{-n}
\ , \quad
c^-_n = \sqrt{2\pi}
\ , \quad
c^+_n = e
\ .
$$
(It should be remarked that alternative bounds are also given by $c^-_n = \sqrt{2\pi} e^{1/(12n+1)}$ and $c^+_n = \sqrt{2\pi} e^{1/(12n)}$, see [Speed of convergence and error estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates)). The double factorial of even numbers, as remarked by Alex (see his comment), can be expressed and bounded by the factorial bounds as
$$
(2k)!! = k! \cdot 2^k \Rightarrow 2^k b^-_{k} \leq (2k)!! \leq 2^k b^+_{k} \quad k \in \mathbb{N}
\ .
$$
The asymptotic 
$$\alpha_n = n^{(n+1)/2} e^{-n/2}$$ 
of Vaclav Kotesovec pointed at by Gerry fulfills for even $n=2k, k \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
2^k b^-_{k} = \sqrt{\pi}\alpha_{2k}
$$
such that the asymptotic delivers lower and upper bounds ($2^k b^+_k = \sqrt{2e}\alpha_{2k}$) for even $n=2k$. Interestingly, for odd $n = 2k+1$, the Vaclav's asymptotic seems to fulfill (I just checked for $k=0,1,2,3,\dots,10^4$ in Mathematica)
$$
\sqrt{2} \alpha_{2k+1} \leq (2k+1)!! \leq \sqrt{e} \alpha_{2k+1}
$$
but I am do not know, if this always holds, or something better than $e$ for an upper bound is possible. Alternatively, you can use the bounds based on the relations to the factorial, see Alex's comment,
$$
(2k+1)!!
=
\frac{(2k+1)!}{k! \cdot 2^k}
\geq
\frac{b^-_{2k+1}}{k! \cdot 2^k}
\geq
\frac{b^-_{2k+1}}{b^+_k \cdot 2^k}
\ .
$$
If you are interested in the use of the $\Gamma(x)$ functions, as suggested by gammatester (see his comment), you may want to use the results of the work of [Necdet Batir](http://rgmia.org/papers/v12n1/AderM-1.pdf) or [Necdet Batir (2017)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00025-017-0698-0). Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Comment: Since $(2n)!!=n!·2^n$ and $(2n+1)!!=\dfrac{(2n+1)!}{(2n)!!}=\dfrac{(2n+1)!}{n!·2^n}$, it reduces to find better bounds for $m!$.

Comment: How about using bounds for the Gamma function or the ordinary factorial with the relations
\begin{align*}
(2k)!!    &= 2^k  k!\\
(2k+1)!!  &= (2k+1)!/(2^k k!) = \frac{2^{k+1}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,\Gamma\left(k+\tfrac{3}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: @AlexFrancisco thank you, you are right, I have to get better bounds for the factorial.

Comment: @gammatester hmmmm, .... that would be intersting, specially using https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6#E8 (last equation)

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Mauricio?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry Gerry, I completely forgot, I have been dealing with another problem these days. I will take a look at your suggestion today and write again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double factorial is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A006882 where there are links to the literature and the asymptotic expression $cn^{(n+1)/2}e^{-n/2}$ where $c=\sqrt{\pi}$ if $n$ is even, $\sqrt2$ if $n$ is odd, attributed to Vaclav Kotesovec.

Comment: Hi Gerry, I took a look at Veclav's asymptotic. I updated my question, you may want to have a look. Thanks for the reference. It actually gave me an idea for another problem :D